# Permission dialog is not being shown android marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Im using nexus 6 android 6.0, only for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission dialog is not showing for other dangerous permission it is showing.

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void insertDummyContactWrapper() {
    int hasWriteContactsPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    110);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
}
```

Build:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.application"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Comment: did you have any luck finding the solution?

Answer (score 3):

> only for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission dialog is not showing for other dangerous permission it is showing

Your other `dangerous` permission is `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. While we ask for permissions and check for permissions, in the Android 6.0 UI, the user grants (or denies) permission *groups*. `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are in the same group.

So, if the user previously granted your request for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, you will already have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at the point in time when you call `checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);`.